# Advice extracting //td text and numbers

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have been working through the tutorial adapting it to a project I want to achieve. I seem to have something going wrong that i just can't find the error to.

When using 'scrapy shell' I can get the response I expect. So for this site [Nrl Ladder](http://live.nrlstats.com/nrl/ladder.html)

```
In [1]: hxs.select('//td').extract()
Out[1]: 
[u'<td>\r\n<div id="ls-nav">\r\n<ul><li><a href="http://www.nrlstats.com/"><span>Home</span></a></li>\r\n<li class="ls-nav-on"><a href="/nrl"><span>NRL</span></a></li>\r\n<li><a href="/nyc"><span>NYC</span></a></li>\r\n<li><a href="/rep"><span>Rep Matches</span></a></li>\r\n\r\n</ul></div>\r\n</td>',
 u'<td style="text-align:left" colspan="5">Round 4</td>',
 u'<td colspan="5">Updated: 26/3/2012</td>',
 u'<td style="text-align:left">1. Melbourne</td>',
 u'<td>4</td>',
 u'<td>4</td>',
 u'<td>0</td>',
 u'<td>0</td>',
 u'<td>0</td>',
 u'<td>122</td>',
 u'<td>39</td>',
 u'<td>83</td>',
 u'<td>8</td>',
 u'<td style="text-align:left">2. Canterbury-Bankstown</td>',
```

And on it goes.

I am really struggling to understand how to alter the tutorial project to change it to a different data type.

Is there anyway to bring up a help or documentation list to see what types I should use in items when using 'td' or any other item. Like i say it works easy in the shell but I cannot transform it to the files. Specifically both the team names and the points are 'td' but the team name is text.

here is what I have done.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from nrl.items import NrlItem

class nrl(BaseSpider):
    name = "nrl"
    allowed_domains = ["http://live.nrlstats.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://live.nrlstats.com/nrl/ladder.html",
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//td')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
           item = nrlItem()
           item['team'] = site.select('/text()').extract()
           item['points'] = site.select('/').extract()
           items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: Have you tried BeautifulSoup? It is a bit more manual, but you might be able to get a bit more control that way

Comment: No not yet but maybe if this doesn't work I will.

Comment: @PreetKukreti it turns out that scrapy can use beautifulsoup as well http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question, but here is a starting point, imo (haven't tested; see some comments in the code):

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from nrl.items import NrlItem

class nrl(BaseSpider):
    name = "nrl"
    allowed_domains = ["live.nrlstats.com"] # domains should be like this
    start_urls = [
        "http://live.nrlstats.com/nrl/ladder.html",
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//table[@class="tabler"]//tr[starts-with(@class, "r")]') # select team rows
        items = []
        for row in rows:
           item = nrlItem()
           columns = row.select('./td/text()').extract() # select columns for the selected row
           item['team'] = columns[0]
           item['P'] = int(columns[1])
           item['W'] = int(columns[2])
           ...
           items.append(item)
        return items
```

UPDATE:

`//table[@class="tabler"//tr[starts-with(@class, "r")]` is an xpath query. See some xpath [examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx).

`hxs.select(xpath_query)` always returns a list of nodes (also of type `HtmlXPathSelector`) which fall under the given query.

`hxs.extract()` returns string representation of the node(s).

P.S. Beware that scrapy supports XPath 1.0, but not 2.0 (at least on Linux, not sure about Windows), so some of the newest xpath features might not work.

See also:

- http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html
- http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/firefox.html

Comment: how do I find extra info on stuff like this line rows = hxs.select('//table[@class="tabler"//tr[starts-with(@class, "r")]') from the tutorial its not obvious thats what I would do.

Comment: This is an xpath question, not related to scrapy. I don't think scrapy docs have this. See my update. I have also added [tag:xpath] tag to your question.

Comment: I receive this error with the Xpath selector   raise ValueError("Invalid XPath: %s" % xpath)
 exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: //table[@class="tabler"//tr[starts-with(@class, "r")]

Comment: sorry, forgot one closing `]`: `//table[@class="tabler"]//tr[starts-with(@class, "r")]`